# Sencha Touch dataview list items are not displaying even though they are populated

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a dataview list view working in another part of my application and is working fine. So I'm using the same principle in another view. I'm trying to display some labels in each row.

I've tried everything to try and get this to work, but to no avail. I've attached a screen-shot of the problem.

It appears the label is in fact in the DOM, but nothing displays.  It also looks like if I select an item, the item selected class isn't added either. Is this a clue as to why it isn't working?

So if the item is in the DOM, why on earth is it not being displayed? In my example I have 2 rows in the DOM, which I inspected using the following selector:

```
Ext.DomQuery.select(".x-data-item");
```

Any help greatly appreciated[image]?

Comment: Can u create a fiddle with this sample? Also if you want to investigate what's wrong with rendering your items - I suggest look closer into CSS properties. You might find some clues here why there are not visible.

Comment: Any ideas what CSS properties I might have a look at? Is there anything in my example that shows CSS properties might not be applied. I have the data list view working elsewhere in my project.

Comment: When you browse through DOM elements in the developer console - you should have panel with detail CSS values on the right. Do you have that?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what I am really looking for. Why can I hover over the DIV but nothing is being displayed? I'm looking for a text color of white or a display: hidden but nothing.

Comment: Try to create a fiddle. It's really hard to say anything by just looking at your screenshot.

Comment: I've tried to create one but it is complaining about the store: http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/kuNJc/

Comment: I've tried to get my Sencha Fiddle working, and now it won't run or save my files. Is Sencha Fiddle broken or something?

Comment: I've created a totally new fiddle which shows my problem. If you could have a look that would be great: http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/Fq0Lj/ The 2nd tab should show a dataview with labels at the top.  The dataview would show if it was an item in the Main view but not if this was then inside another view (in this case view2).

Comment: This fiddle getting the error 'Failed to save files'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30144/discussion-between-jaffa-and-sha)